# How will be behavior if same private instance variable is defined in both parent and child?

Tags: java

Case 1: In following code, if child only inherits(does not override) getPrivateString, calling getPrivateString using reference of child object returns value of Parent variable. Output = "Variable: private access specifier in Parent Class".

Case 2: In following code, if child overrides getPrivateString (with defination same as parent), calling getPrivateString using reference of child object returns  value of Child variable. Output = "Variable: private access specifier in Child Class".
Can anybody please throw some light on this,as, in inheritance, methods just virtually seats in code of child defination. I want to understand the variable selection process.

Parent.java

```
package learnInheritance.parent;

public class Parent 
{

    private String privateString = "Variable: private access specifier in Parent Class";

    public String getPrivateString()
    {
        return this.privateString;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()    
    {
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }

}
```

Child.java

```
package learnInheritance.child;

import learnInheritance.parent.Parent;

public class Child extends Parent
{

    private String privateString = "Variable: private access specifier in Child Class";

    /*
    @Override
    public String getPrivateString()
    {
        return this.privateString;
    }
    */
    @Override
    public String toString()    
    {
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }


    public static void main(String [] str)
    {
        Parent parent=new Parent(); 
        Child child=new Child();

        System.out.println("parent.getPrivateString() = " + parent.getPrivateString());
        System.out.println("child.getPrivateString() = " + child.getPrivateString());


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`private` fields (by definition) are not inherited. Your "second case" is called [variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) and occurs when (from the Wikipedia article) *a variable declared within a certain scope (decision block, method, or inner class) has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope.*

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the `Child` does not override the method, so the `Parent` method is called, and references its own variable.
In the second example, the `Child` method is called, and it references the variable in `Child`.

Child classes cannot access private members of their parent classes. Parent classes cannot access **any** variables in their children classes. In other words, there is no such thing as "variable overriding" - overriding is just for methods.